# How can I change this sentence into passive voice ?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

Question: I study with Mrs.Cara 
Answer: I am studied with Mrs.Cara 
Or I am made to study with Mrs.Cara

Which one is correct ? Please help me !

Answer (score 2):

Study is intransitive in this case and thus cannot be made passive. Only transitive verbs cane be made into passive voice.

> I am studied with Mrs. Cara

This implies that someone other than you and Mrs. Cara is studying you and her. It's an unusual sentence but grammatical, but also not the passive form of your original sentence.

> I am made to study with Mrs. Cara

This implies someone is causing you to study with Mrs. Cara. It's grammatical, but not the passive version of the original.

Answer (score 1):

"Study" can be *both* an **intransitive verb** (takes one noun, the someone/thing doing the action) or a **transitive verb** (takes two nouns, subject which does the action and object which receives the action)

> Active: [someone or something S] **studies** [someone or something O].
>
> Passive: [someone or something O] **is studied by** [someone or something S].

As you can see, you just switch the two nouns.  In your first answer:

> I am studied with Mrs. Cara.

You are the [someone or something O].  Like, say, a police officer is studying *you* to see if you are a criminal.  This changes the meaning from your original active sentence, where you were the [someone or something S].  Almost nobody would say this new sentence because the reader of the sentence would certainly be interested in who you are being studied by!

Your second answer:

> I[O] am made to study with Mrs. Cara (by my teacher [S]).

Be careful!  This is a valid passive construction.  However, you are now the object of the verb "made to", something which was not in the original sentence.  It works since even though you're the object of "made", you are still understood to be the subject for "study".

To make the pure sentence from active to passive for a transitive verb, you need to make sure you know **both** the [A] and the [B].  What are you studying?

So a pure sentence, where you don't add any unnecessary meaning, looks like this:

> Math [B] was studied by me [A] with Mrs. Cara.

You can also optionally drop the [A].  ("by" part)

> Math was studied with Mrs. Cara.

This sentence is quite awkward for a native speaker.  Most of the time, using the active tense is better.

As a side note, passive voice is impossible with **intransitive verbs** such as to sleep.  The only way to make a passive sentence is to do what you did, and change the verb to "make", a transitive verb.

> I was made to sleep [by my mother].
>
> I was made to study [by my teacher].

Be aware that adding the verb "make" adds extra meaning to the sentence, since it implies someone is influencing you to do it.